# Where is the Power BI specific R syntax documentation?

Tags: r, powerbi, powerquery

I am completely new in R. I have been learning Power BI.

I'm forced to learn R because I want to use Regex in Power Query.

I am learning the helloworld of R in Power Query. Here is the script.

```
library(dplyr)
iris_mean <- summarize(group_by(dataset, Species), slength = mean(Sepal.Length), swidth = mean(Sepal.Width), plength = mean(Petal.Length), pwidth = mean(Petal.Width))
```

I have never seen "dataset" in Power Query Syntax. Is it R specific keyword? Where can I find the documentation? Also $ seems to specify the data column of the dataset. Where is it documented?

I want to know further about the integration of R in Power Query and more keywords of data manipulation.

Comment: Avoid Microsoft products if you are dealing with R.  They don't really know what they are doing.  To answer your question:  no, `dataset` is a variable name in that context, it is not a keyword. Install R, then read An Introduction to R (or one of the many books about it), don't expect Microsoft to document it properly.  Have they ever documented *anything* properly?

Comment: R isn't a Microsoft language or product so I wouldn't expect them to document it. The `dataset` usually refers to the data that you are passing from M to R, but it's just a name, not a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

In your context, `dataset` is probably a variable name containing a dataframe (How arrays are called in R) with the actual data.

You may find R's documentation in their official [website](https://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html). As noted in one of the comments, you may find the first reading useful to understand the basics of the language.

Additionally, Power BI is slowly improving its integration with R and Python. Microsoft also distributes an [open source alternative for R engine](https://mran.microsoft.com/) but they do not document it very well.

In the other hand, they document the entirety of M language (Power Query) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/).